# Webpack - ignore loaders in require()?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have a TypeScript project which I am bundling with Webpack. It is a demo/docs app for an open source lib I am writing, so I want to show some of the source code as part of the docs.

In my webpack config I have:

```
 loaders: [
   { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts'},
   { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!raw' },
   { test: /\.html/, loader: 'html' }
 ]
```

which works fine for transpiling and bundling my TypeScript files. In one of my app components I do this:

```
basicCodeT: string = require('./basic-example-cmp.html');
basicCodeC: string = require('!raw!./basic-example-cmp.ts');
```

to load the source code into a string which I then want to display in the docs.

As you can see, there is a leading `!` in the second line which I discovered seems to "bypass" the default loaders from the config and loads the raw TypeScript as a string.

In my dev build this works, but when I do a "production" build with the UglifyJsPlugin and OccurrenceOrderPlugin, I get the following output:

```
ERROR in ./demo/src/basic-example-cmp.html
Module build failed: 
@ ./demo/src/demo-app.ts 24:26-61
```

which corresponds to the line in the source where I try to require the raw TypeScript.

So, **I want to pass `basic-example-cmp.ts` through the TS compiler as part of the app build, but *also* want to require it as raw text in the app**.

My question then is: **Is there a proper way to tell webpack to "ignore" loaders in specific require cases?**

**Is my way of prepending a `!` correct? Is it a hack?**

### Update

Turns out my problem is simply due to the way Webpack handles HTML templates - it does not like the Angular 2 template syntax, see: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/992

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add two exclamation to ignore loaders in the webpack config file

`!!raw!file.ts`

one exclamation will only disable preloaders!

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks. I still find the Webpack docs very difficult to navigate.

Comment: Webpack is soo configable :P

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know that is the only way you are going to be able to load a file in two different ways. I expect the issue is that your paths are different in your production build.

I would suggest running webpack with the `--display-error-details` flag to get more info on why it fails.

Comment: Thanks. Okay, then perhaps the issue is something else as you suggest - I will see what I can find out with that flag enabled.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a proper way to tell webpack to "ignore" loaders in specific require cases?

Yes. Update your `test` in `{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts'},` as desired.

Comment: Hi, I should clarify that I *do* want to transpile `basic-example-cmp.ts` as part of my app, but I *also* want to load it as a string in that same app, this time not transpiled. I'll update the question to make that clear.